# LNK2038 Error when adding Boost lib into Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, boost, runtime, versions

I'm working on a C++ application in Qt and got to a point where the compiler is at least able to open the included boost library files. Now I get:

> LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'runtimelibrary' value
>   'MTd_StaticDebug' does not match 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj

So, I have skimmed other threats about this issue. The compiler version of Qt (msvc 2014) matches the one of the lib-files (i.e. `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-1_61`). This is my include for the debug-version (haven't tried release yet because that one has other issues to be solved later).

```
win32:CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
# debug
LIBS += -L$$PWD/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/msvc-14.0/debug/address-model-64/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-1_61
LIBS += -L$$PWD/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/msvc-14.0/debug/address-model-64/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_61
LIBS += -L$$PWD/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/address-model-64/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61
}
```

Now, it seems that there might be something wrong with the runtime settings (/MD, /MT) but - tbh I have no idea how to check that or fix it.

Comment: Those library search paths look a little ridiculous -- it seems to me that you didn't do the `install` step after compiling boost (and to be honest, I don't recall ever seeing even output of `stage` to look like this).

Comment: You certainly should not be linking to both `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-1_61` and `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_61` -- they're both the same library, both static, one using the dynamic runtime, the other static runtime.

Comment: @DanMašek Deleting the `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-1_61` worked, thanks for your time. P.S.: That's indeed the output of `stage` I got.